# Xbee explorer in pc communication with Xbee in arduino

Tags: arduino, communication, explorer, xbee

I have a Xbee explorer on the pc, and one arduino with the arduino wireless shield with another Xbee there. Using XCTU I can receive data from the arduino to the PC but not the other way around, sending using XCTU to the arduino.
If I send from the XCTU only the led RSSI from the arduino wireless shield is on but it should be the RX led.

This is the tutorial I'm using [Link](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/xbee-shield-hookup-guide)

Here's the code I'm using on the arduino, booth antennas are S1 Xbee antennas and the antennas are all default values restore

```cpp
// We'll use SoftwareSerial to communicate with the XBee:
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial XBee(10,11); // RX, TX

void setup()
{
  // Set up both ports at 9600 baud. This value is most important
  // for the XBee. Make sure the baud rate matches the config
  // setting of your XBee.
  XBee.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available())
  { // If data comes in from serial monitor, send it out to XBee
    Serial.println("first if");
    XBee.write(Serial.read());
  }

  if (XBee.available())
  { // If data comes in from XBee, send it out to serial monitor
    Serial.println("second if");
    Serial.write(XBee.read());
  }
}
```

Comment: If you swap the physical XBee modules between the Arduino and the XBee Explorer, what happens?  Does data still flow from the Arduino to X-CTU, or does it only go in the other direction?  If the direction changes, it's related to how the radios are configured.  Make sure the `DH` and `DL` values on the coordinator correspond to the `SH` and `SL` values on the router.

Comment: If I switch them the problem continues, the arduino sends and the X-CTU receives but if a try to send from the X-CTU nothing appends. I have try the value of the DH and DL and the SH and SL and the problem continues.

Comment: OK, so you've confirmed it's a problem sending from X-CTU or receiving on the Arduino.  Both XBee modules are capable of receiving data from the other.  Have you enabled hardware handshaking on the XBee modules?  If so, the Arduino needs to assert RTS before the XBee module will send it data.  Take a look at ATD6 and ATD7, making sure they're disabled on the Arduino's XBee (since Arduino serial ports don't support hardware handshaking).

Comment: Hello tomlogic thank you for all the answers but I have disabled the ATD7 and ATD6 from the Xbee on the Arduino and the problem continues.

Comment: You'd want to verify the hardware configuration of the shield, possibly connecting a logic analyzer to the XBee module's `DOUT` pin to see if any information comes through.

Answer (score 0):

Please precise the operating mode on your two xbee modules thier model( it can be hard to communicate when using XBEE3), and their DL, DH

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30137329)